# Adding Google+ Sign in button to website

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to add a HTML sign-in button to my website using Google+ but I'm having a few issues.

I've followed the instructions given by Google on  [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button)  but I'm stuck on step 5 - Handle the sign-in.

I am unsure how and where to enter the following code.

Javascript:

```js
function signinCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
    // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for example:
    document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
  } else {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
    // Possible error values:
    //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
    //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
    //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
    console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }
}
```

The button appears when previewed in browser but doesn't appear to work. Can anyone offer any insight?

Answer (score 0):

`signinCallback` is simply the Javascript function that you named in the `data-callback` attribute of your button:

```
<span id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-callback="signinCallback" <!-- HERE -->
    data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
  </span>
</span>
```

Because it is just a normal function, you can place it anywhere on your page (don't forget to wrap it in `<script></script>`.

Common practice is to place your Javascript at the foot of your document to ensure that any elements referenced have been loaded before you try to access them.